# jQuery on() Not Firing For Dynamic Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this click handler not called after adding an element to the list?

```
<div id="a">
    <a href="#" class="a1">Test</a>
</div>

<div id="b">
    <div class="b1">
        <ul id="list">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="b2">Test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>    
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Add One</button>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a').on('click', '> .a1', function(){ alert('works')})
    $('#b').on('click', '> .b1 > ul > li > .b2', function(){ alert('works')})

    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#list').append('<a href="#" class="b2">Test Added</a>')
    })
})
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/eV4rX/

Comment: Ugh... it needed to be wrapped in an <li>:  $('#list').append('<li><a href="#" class="b2">Test Added</a></li>')

Answer (score 3):

It needed to be wrapped in an `<li>`:

```
$('#list').append('<li><a href="#" class="b2">Test Added</a></li>')
```

Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/eV4rX/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can have simply

```
$('#b').on('click', 'a', function(){ alert('works')})
```

instead of

```
$('#b').on('click', '> .b1 > ul > li > .b2', function(){ alert('works')})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eV4rX/3/

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with on() and everything to do with the markup you're appending.  Wrap the `<a>` in a `<li>` so that it matches your second selector there.

http://jsfiddle.net/TJ8Yy/

`$('#list').append('<li><a href="#" class="b2">Test Added</a></li>')`

Comment: Bah.  Didn't save.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

first you should append li to list
your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a').find('.a1').on('click', function(){ alert('works1');});
    $('#b').on('click', 'a', function(){ alert('works2')})

    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#list').append('<li><a href="#" class="b2">Test Added</a></li>');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eV4rX/6/)

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer:

```
$('#list').on('click', '.b2', function() {
     alert('works');
});
```